# Android 3.0 (HoneyComb) context menu question

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-3.0-honeycomb

When I try to show context menu in Android 3.0 instead of normal menu I see smth like in this picture[image: screen shot] - which is basically text edit/select menu.

On other devices (e.g. for SDK 5-9) it shows my context menu registered for my `TextView`

Anyone knows - what's going om?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by entering in `AndroidManifest.xml` following snippet:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

After that context menu in tablets is appearing as on other devices. Essential part is `android:tagetSdkVersion` attribute